# How to configure IIS 8.5 to accept translated IPv4->IPv6 address in host header

Tags: iis, azure, ipv6

I have an application which is operating from an IPv6 only network, making HTTP requests to an IPv4 only server on the internet (using NAT64).
Requests are made by IP address, not host name.

As a result, the server (IIS 8.5) receives a connection, and the payload includes an HTTP Host header containing an IPv6 encoded IPv4 address ; i.e.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: [::ffff:abc:abcd]
```

The IIS server then spits the dummy, return HTTP 400 "The request hostname is invalid."

I have configured IIS for this:
[image]

What am I missing with my configuration to make this work?

Note: My server is an Azure VM - if that makes any difference.

Comment: Accessing literal IPv4 addresses via HTTP doesn't work very well via NAT64. Use a name instead.

Comment: Hi Michael. "Doesn't work very well", or "Doesn't work at all"? I'm looking for an answer specific to IIS as NAT64 has nothing to do with the situation after the packets hit the internet... Using a name is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: As far as I can tell, "doesn't work at all" is closer to being accurate. You need to _make_ using a name an option, or get native IPv6 at both ends of the connection.

Comment: I've run a similar test on IIS10 (granted *similar* not *identical*) and IIS10 accepts the IPv6 host header as an IP address rather than a host name - so it works. It *appears* that the situation is, despite numerous documents about IIS8.5 supporting IPv6 - it is, in fact, broken with regards to identifying that a host header is an v6 IP address?

Comment: I would have expected a header looking more like this `Host: [64:ff9b::c000:201]`.